# Suppressing "STDOUT message(s) from external script:" in SQL Server with r

Tags: r, sql-server

I'm currently running SQL Server Management Studio v17 with R. My R code has a bunch of output going to a log file. Every 10 lines or so, I get the following message:

> STDOUT message(s) from external script:

Is there anyway to suppress this message? Not sure of the option to use (it's not `max.print`)